# 2 players steal at the same time on 2 outs

Tags: rules, baseball

There are runners on 1st and 3rd, 2 outs, and while a pitch is in progress, the runner on 1st attempts to steal 2nd. The catcher throws to 2nd, and the runner is caught in a pickle, eventually tagged out. During the pickle, the runner at 3rd steals and reaches home before the runner at 1st is declared out.

Does the run scored count? Or does the 3rd out supersede the run scored?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Does the run scored count?

Yes.

> Does the 3rd out supersede the run scored?

No.

The only way the 3rd out supersedes the run scored, in this case, is if the out took place before the run was scored. However, based on your scenario (ie, "the runner at 3rd steals and reaches home before the runner at 1st is declared out"), this isn't the case.

---

Rule 5.08(a) in the [2016 MLB Rulebook](http://mlb.mlb.com/mlb/downloads/y2016/official_baseball_rules.pdf) states (emphasis mine):

> One run shall be scored each time a runner legally advances to and
>   touches first, second, third and home base **before** three men are put
>   out to end the inning.

Comment: I like this answer, but I think it maybe important to point out that this is different from a force out situation.